# How can I use findViewById for android:id?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, findviewbyid

I want to use `findViewById` for my `expandableListView`, 
the `android:id` has to be `@android:id/list referred` to the warning message of compiler. 
I can't use `R.id.list` to find it out in a class, 
how can I find it?

p.s. I would like to set one group to be expanded in default, 
`list.expandGroup(int);`

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/

Answer (score 3):

Call `findViewById(android.R.id.list)` to retrieve a widget that was defined as `android:id="@android:id/list"`.